# Magento 2 : Page Layout is not Updating as Expected for catalog_category_view.xml

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.4

I am trying to change the layout of my catalog_category_view.xml from `2columns-left` to `1column`, however the change is not reflecting on the FE.

I cleared all available caches. Did I made a mistake?

The file is located here: `app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[namespace]/Magento_catalog/layout/`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Confirm any third party extension overide the sme xml file or not.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to rewrite the `Magento_PageBuilder` page_layout XML.

File: `app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[namespace]/Magento_PageBuilder/page_layout/catalog_category_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

</page>
```

Comment: No, your first solution should work. I'm doing the same thing. You might have a typo. It should be Magento_Catalog and not Magento_catalog.

Answer (score 0):

The right path of `catalog_category_view.xml` file is this one :

> app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Namespace]/Magento_Catalog/layout/

Comment: As you can see in the main error, this is exactly the file I am changing